# How to create Solr schema for collection using api in Solr Cloud mode?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr9

I created new collection

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:8983/api/collections \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "create": {
    "name": "members",
    "numShards": 1,
    "replicationFactor": 1
  }
}'
```

And by default predefined schema _default is used. How can I create my own schema and assign it to this collection?

Solr vesion: 9.2

I know, that in Solr Cloud mode I can't just simply create schema.xml inside solr node. Should I import somehow schema to Zookeeper?

Comment: Have you seen the Schema API? https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/schema-api.html Another option: using `upconfig` to upload configuration files: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/zookeeper-utilities.html#upload-a-configuration-directory

Comment: Yes I have seen Schema API, but I didn't find any information about how to actually create schema. There was only information about managing of existing schemas.
Regarding upconfig. I'm running sorl cloud with docker-compose, and I have zookeeper in a separate container. Do I need to run the commands from the documentation inside the containers with solr or inside the containers with zookeeper?

Comment: You'll have to run upconfig from a location where you have zkCli and the configuration file, and against the zookeeper containers (since that's where you're uploading to). Ref creating a schema: you can use the configset API to create a new configset (and skip upconfig): https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/configsets-api.html. You can also create it by giving the default configset as the base, then use the schemaapi to modify that.